# Sun Grid Engine resubmit job stuck in 'Rq' state

Tags: grid-computing, sungridengine

I have what I hope is a pretty simple question, but I'm not super familiar with Sun Grid, so I've been having trouble finding the answer. I am currently submitting jobs to a grid using a bash submission script that generates a command and then executes it. I have read online that if a sun grid job exits with a code of 99, it gets re-submitted to the grid. I have successfully written my bash script to do this:

```
[code to generate command, stores in $command]
$command
STATUS=$?
if [[ $STATUS -ne 0 ]]; then
    exit 99
fi
exit 0
```

When I submit this job to the grid with a command that I know has a non-zero exit status, the job does indeed appear to be resubmitted, however the scheduler never sends it to another host, instead it just remains stuck in the queue with the status "Rq":

```
job-ID  prior   name       user         state submit/start at     queue                          slots ja-task-ID
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2150015 0.55500 GridJob.sh my_user      Rq    04/08/2013 17:49:00                                    1
```

I have a feeling that this is something simple in the config options for the queue, but I haven't been able to find anything googling. I've tried submitting this job with the `qsub -r y` option, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Thanks!

Comment: What does Rq state stands for??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rescheduled jobs will only get run in queues that have their `rerun` attribute (FALSE by default) set to TRUE, so check your queue configuration (`qconf -mq myqueue`). Without this, your job remains in the rescheduled-pending state indefinitely because it has nowhere to go.

IIRC, submitting jobs with `qsub -r yes` only qualifies them for automatic rescheduling in the event of an exec node crash, and that exiting with status 99 should trigger a reschedule regardless.